# recompile source code in java method?

Tags: java

Currently want to work out some function like using Jpanel to edit source code and recompile it.

The basic ideal the basic java game I have with using Java.swing to perform. Instead of just showing the game, I will like to show part of the code with just pressing a button. The code will show out and let user to edit, save it with replace the original code.

The coming challenging function wanted to perform is how can the system recompile with pressing one button in the Jpanel? I figure out there's difficulty when wanted to replace the original code and recompile.

Any idea in Java can perform such functionality? Will be appreciated on any comment and guidelines. Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with integrating a scripting language? A billion times easier (and that's still quite a task, mind you).

Comment: @delnan I am not so sure what it means by integrating a scripting language... How can I perform that? you mean apply it on the web?

Comment: java 1.6 does have quite some scripting languages build in, for example javascipt. Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino_%28JavaScript_engine%29 for example

Comment: What aspects of the game should be user configurable?  Game maps/levels, weapons/powers, characters and even 'laws of physics' might better be supplied as parameters to existing classes.  (The last, for example, being formulae handed to the `ScriptEngine`.)

Answer (score 1):

See [JavaCompiler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html). Requires JDK on classpath.

Comment: That's the easy part. The hard to impossible part is replacing the running code with the newly compiled one...

Comment: Replacing the running code is not impossible anymore :) have a look at the Dynamic Code Evolution VM: http://ssw.jku.at/dcevm/

Comment: @mglauche: You'd have to get it onto the user's computer though.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you would call javac in your code, and write the output of the interpreter to a place where another part of your code would load it using a custom class loader.

To answer your meta-question, what's to prevent malicious users from entering destructive code?  There's a reason games have a configuration file and possibly a scripting language.  You want people to be able to modify certain parameters of the game, and not other parameters.

Comment: Re second paragraph: At least [according to gamedev.SE, the main reason for scripting language is the flexibility of scripts](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2913/why-do-we-use-scripts-in-development)...

Comment: @delnan:  True.  From the point of view of the game player, scripts make the game flexible.  From the point of view of the developer of the game, scripts are allowed access to certain methods or functions, and not others.  Access is still controlled.

Answer (score 0):

The technique you're looking for is call [Hotswapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotswap#Software). You can accomplish that in the JVM using some of the debugging hooks as described, for example, [here](http://another-lazy-blogger.blogspot.com/2008/04/how-to-hotswap-classes-in-running.html).